# Unit test fails in maven but not in Intelij Idea

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

In my project I modified the pom.xml. 
I changed a library version from 1.0.66 to **1.0.74**.
When I run **mvn clean install** a unit test fails, but it doesn't fail in Intelij Idea.

I checked the .m2 folder to see if maven uses the correct version, but seems to look fine.

This is the version from .m2 and in Intelij Idea looks identically.

```
<lib_name>1.0.74</lib_name>
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong??

Comment: Can you show your entire POM or a least give the whole error message that you read ?

Comment: Please provide error that you receive when you try mvn clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I did from Indelij Idea ---> Invalidate Caches/Restart, now the test fails also in Intelij Idea, maybe something got stuck somewhere.